# Expandable Listview with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got an issue while developing an app in android. I didn't find the solution after doing a lot of searches.

An app having two fragment panels.First one, a `Fragment` showing the list of categories and sub categories where user can select a category or more specifically its sub category. Then its appropriate description will displayed on second fragment.

I'm using an expandable `view` for the category list. But I got an error during run time.

> System service not available to activities before onCreate()

Following are xml and code used in my app

**activity_main_base.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainBase" >
   <LinearLayout
       style="@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle"
        android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="50dp">

   </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/categoryfragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

**MainBase.java**

```
package my.newapp.x;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;


public class MainBase extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_base);
        Fragment f=new Jobcat();
        FragmentManager fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.categoryfragment,f);
        ft.commit();

    }
}
```

**catlayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:childIndicatorRight="30dp"
        >        
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**jobcat.java**

```
package my.newapp.x;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class Jobcat extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.catlayout,container,false);
        return v;

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        try{
         categoryfill j =new categoryfill();
         j.fillme();

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Errrr +++ " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

**categoryfill.java**

```
package my.newapp.x;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;

public class Jobcategoryfill extends ExpandableListActivity {

    private SimpleExpandableListAdapter listadapter;
    ExpandableListView expand;

    public  void fillme()
    {
      List<Map<String,String>> category=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
      List<List<Map<String, String>>> subcategory=new ArrayList<List<Map<String,String>>>();

      Map<String,String> cat1=new HashMap<String, String>();
      cat1.put("Parent","A");
      category.add(cat1);

      List<Map<String,String>> sublist1=new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

      Map<String,String> sub11=new HashMap<String, String>();
      sub11.put("child","a1");
      sublist1.add(sub11);
      Map<String,String> sub12=new HashMap<String, String>();
      sub12.put("child","a2");
      sublist1.add(sub12);
      Map<String,String> sub13=new HashMap<String, String>();
      sub13.put("child","a3");
      sublist1.add(sub13);
      Map<String,String> sub14=new HashMap<String, String>();
      sub14.put("child","a4");
      sublist1.add(sub14);
              sublist1.add(sub115);
              subcategory.add(sublist1);


      listadapter=new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(this, category, R.layout.categoryparent, new String[] { "Parent" },new int[]{R.id.parentview}, 
                    subcategory, R.layout.categorychild, new String[]{"child"},new int[]{R.id.childview});
      setListAdapter(listadapter);
    }


}
```

I am unable to find the solution. Pleas anyone help me to resolve this issue or suggest me another method to implement this concept.

Answer (score 0):

This below line should be pretty much explain the problem.

`System service not available to activities before onCreate()`

You should use the method `onCreate()` instead of `onCreateView()`.

Comment: how i can create oncreate for a fragment instad of  on create view

Comment: can you post your stacktrace? may be you did this in your MainActivity rather than your Fragment?

Comment: but i need to display this in a fragment...then only it will be useful for large screen sizes